# Public python program as one file with all modules included

Tags: python, opencv, build, project

I am new in Python, and I wonder if I can release my program in some kind of compiled build project with all modules and librarys included, so I can run it on diffrent systems? I don't want to install opencv on every pc.

Comment: "I don't want to install opencv on every pc" -- There are projects which are made to distribute the third-party libraries that you need (e.g. [`py2exe`](http://www.py2exe.org/)) with your project all packaged in a neat "binary".

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a `requirements.txt` file which lists the dependencies used by your program. Python pip can read this file to bundle and package your application. See the docs here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files.

Also, I believe that OpenCV requires some native extensions installed which are not packaged with Python. Unfortunately, you'll need to install native extensions on each new machine you use.

Comment: great track, but what about linux? Is there any "exe-like" file which could be run as "safe for non-linux user" on ubuntu etc?

Comment: Not really. Remember, Python is a dynamic language and requires the Python runtime in order to actually run as a program. It doesn't exactly compile down to native executable assembly the same way that C does. Therefore Python code is almost always run as a script, not as a binary.

Comment: So if I use C i could compile "exe-like" file with all libraries (with opencv and numpy) and run it on linux? The best way is to use exe and wine or diffrent file and run it on clear linux?

Comment: You could possibly bundle it will all libraries as long as there were no compatibility issues, though you could just do the same thing in Python by using an install script. Python is commonly installed on Linux/Unix installs anyways so I don't see a big difference here. The only advantage, albeit significant, with using C is that you'll get much higher performance than Python at the cost of greater complexity.

Comment: There are 2 reasons i want this sollution:
-installing opencv and couple more on older/weaker devices takes too long and makes problem with compatibility
-i just want to send one file for my parents to run it :)